# Specify if date is a weekend and/or a holiday PHP

Tags: php, date, if-statement

I need to write a program  that generates a random date

```
$start = strtotime('2010-01-01');
$end =  strtotime('2018-01-01');
$random_date = date('n F Y l ', rand($start, $end));
```

then I need to translate the names of months and days into russian

```
$lat = array ('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
$rus = array ('Воскресенье', 'Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда', 'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота', 'Января', 'Февраля', 'Марта', 'Апреля', 'Июня', 'Июля', 'Августа', 'Сентября', 'Октября', 'Ноября', 'Декабря');
return str_replace($lat,$rus, $random_date) ;
```

```
$holidays = array('8 января','7 января','14 января', '23 февраля','8 марта','1 апреля','12 апреля','1 мая','9 мая','12 июня','22 июня','1 сентября','27 сентября','4 ноября','12 декабря','31 декабря','1 января');//dates of rus holidays
```

Then I need to display the date in this format:
2 Февраля 2014 Пятница  (2 February 2014 Friday).

Here's what I am having trouble with:

The end result must look like this: 2 February 2014 Friday holiday and/or weekend. 
So, I need to specify whether the displayed date is a weekend or/ and a holiday. Could someone help?

Comment: It's easy enough to figure out if a day is a Saturday or Sunday, but how exactly do you figure out whether it's a holiday? In what country, for starters?

Comment: Where is the definition of holy days? Why do you place week's days with months in the same array? show us some of conditionals that you have tried.

Comment: @SaidbakR they're in the same array because I need to replace english names for days of the weeks and months into russian. So it's done for the sake of this part here: 'return str_replace($lat,$rus, $random_date) ;'

Comment: The holidays you must set yourself what day to be a holiday, example in a array or database in a year, PHP can't define it

Comment: @deceze I'm having trouble figuring out if it's a weekend for a random date... not sure if i make sense. Holidays for russia. I suppose I'm going to need an array of those as well.

Comment: @RendiWahyudiMuliawan good point. Thank you. On it.

Comment: @deceze did you have to put my question on hold? Really? Couldn't have just asked to specify if it didn't make sense to you? i edited the question with step by step instructions of my thought process JUST for you. *eyeroll

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98026/476

Comment: @deceze still a bit petty. Just ask and a person will gladly edit their question. It's called teamwork.

Comment: It worked out, didn't it? Great work, team!

Answer (score 0):

You put the date in $date, then we set $weekend to false until we check it, then we check the date and if it is a weekend set $weekend to true. then if the date is a weekend I print it is a weekend and if it is not i print it is not a weekend, but you can do anything you like with it...

```
date = '2018-03-16';
$weekend = false;
$day = date("D", strtotime($date));
if($day == 'Sat' || $day == 'Sun'){
    $weekend = true;
}
if($weekend){
    echo $date . ' It is a weekend';
} else{
    echo $date . ' It is not a weekend';
}
```

and as function(didnt test this one yet):

```
function isitweekend($date){
$date = '2018-03-16';
$weekend = false;
$day = date("D", strtotime($date));
if($day == 'Sat' || $day == 'Sun'){
    $weekend = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For start, lets make a function that will return random date:

```php
function randomDate($start_date, $end_date) 
{
    $min = new DateTime($start_date . ' 00:00:00 UTC');
    $max = new DateTime($end_date . ' 23:59:59 UTC');
    return new DateTime('@' . rand($min->getTimestamp(), $max->getTimestamp()));
}
```

Then just created `while` loop which checks for weekends and holidays:

```php
// Fill this array with your holidays
$holidays = ['*-12-25', '*-01-01', '*-01-07', '*-05-01'];

while (true) {
    // Get random date
    $randomDate = randomDate('2010-01-01', '2018-01-01');

    // Get random date again, since this one is on weekend.
    if ($randomDate->format('N') >= 6) continue;

    // Get random date again, since this one is on holiday.
    if (in_array($randomDate->format('*-m-d'), $holidays)) continue;

    // Exit the loop, since random date is ok!
    break;
}

// Random date
echo $randomDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

And then just transform day and month names to your language.

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/975666)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to check for International Holidays here is a function I wrote for it.

```
function checkHoliday($date){
  if(date('l', strtotime($date)) == 'Saturday'){
    return "Saturday";
  }else if(date('l', strtotime($date)) == 'Sunday'){
    return "Sunday";
  }else{
    $receivedDate = date('d M', strtotime($date));

    $holiday = array(
      '01 Jan' => 'New Year Day',
      '18 Jan' => 'Martin Luther King Day',
      '22 Feb' => 'Washington\'s Birthday',
      '05 Jul' => 'Independence Day',
      '11 Nov' => 'Veterans Day',
      '24 Dec' => 'Christmas Eve',
      '25 Dec' => 'Christmas Day',
      '31 Dec' => 'New Year Eve'
    );

    foreach($holiday as $key => $value){
      if($receivedDate == $key){
        return $value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And call it this way

```
$date = '01/01/2021';

echo checkHoliday($date);
```

Yes, you will have to manually add the holidays to the array above.